# Looking for a typecasting capability in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a query that returns whether a record is public or private.  If the record is public, the user_id column for that record is zero.  Otherwise, it is a positive integer.  I'd like the query to return a one if the user_id is greater than zero and a zero if it is zero.  In PHP, I would probably just cast it to a binary.  This doesn't work in mysql, but I'm hoping that there is something else that is similar.  I could always use an if statement, but figured there might be something a little more elegant.

```
SELECT (binary)user_id as is_private FROM mytable WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  user_id > 0 AS is_private
FROM    mytable
```

It will return `BOOLEAN` datatype which in `MySQL` is just a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`

Note that it will not work when `user_id` is a `NULL` (it will return `NULL` as well), but since your question only mentions zeros and positive integers, I post this without `NULL` checking.